# How to read file/write to a file in UWP C++

Tags: c++, uwp

So does anyone know how to write/read files in UWP C++? "Normal" file streams that worked for me before in console apps like fstream doesn't work, I've been googling that for hours and I learned that UWP has no access for anything. I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files but it's C# and everything else in the internet is C# aswell.. can't copy with that, I got stuck.

My program is a simple password manager, what I want to do is implement 2 functions:

1. read 3 TextBoxes, get stuff from it and put it one line then add the line to a file
2. read whole file full of passwords and put it in a TextBlock

Help please

Comment: With regard to C#  vs. CLI/C++: you're just going to have to mentally transcribe from C# syntax.  It isn't hard.  With regard to your question: these articles might help: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/05/18/console-uwp-applications-and-file-system-access/ and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3176132d-d023-4c1d-9797-f5ed711b0ee8/uwpcare-ifstreamofstream-allowed-in-universal-windows-platform?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Simply give your UWP app `broadFileSystemAccess` permission, then you'll be able to use any normal file I/O like fstreams etc.

Comment: The [FileAccess sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess) is available in C++. "cpp" contains the C++/CX version (a nonstandard Microsoft extension). "cppwinrt" contains the C++/WinRT version, which is standard C++.